# Dúvida entre o Any() e o All() numa expressão lambda em uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista

Em uma lista, tenho 12 registros (hipotético) e há um campo chamado `ValorCampoFlag`, onde esse campo recebe 1 ou `null`, por exemplo. Caso eu faça uma validação nele e o resultado caso haja pelo menos um com valor 1, eu devo usar `Any` ou `All`?

```
minhaVarBool = minhaLista.All(l => l.ValorCampoFlag == 1);
```

Ou assim:

```
minhaVarBool = minhaLista.Any(l => l.ValorCampoFlag == 1);
```

Qual estratégia devo usar para esse tipo de resultado, ou seja, setar uma variável booleana.

A lista me trás vários registros e basta haver um nessa condição para setar a variável.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação de [`Any()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) e [`All()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_All__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) se a sua descrição estiver correta você deve usar o **`Any`**. Ela retorna `true` se qualquer dos elementos satisfaz a condição estabelecida.

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

*Any* é "qualquer", portanto se qualquer elemento tenha esta condição retornará um `true`, basta um. Ele procurará até achar um elemento que dê `true`, e não faz sentido continuar buscando todos, portanto pode ser muito rápido se achar entre os primeiros elementos.

*All* é "todos", portanto se todos os elementos tiverem esta condição retornará `true`. Ele tem que avaliar todos os elementos sempre.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A opção 'Any' também possui melhor desempenho, pois, ao encontrar o primeiro item da lista que atende à condição ele para o processo de enumeração, enquanto o All verifica sempre todos os itens da lista.