# Há como comparar todos os parâmetros recebidos em um método com "params"?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Tenho o seguinte método

```
public Boolean Teste(String nome, String telefone, String...)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nome) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telefone)...) {}
}
```

Há como comparar todos esses valores recebidos de um jeito mais simples?

Comment: O que deseja fazer? Tem um jeito simples, mas depende da sua necessidade

Comment: criando uma model e usando a validação do DataAnotation

Comment: @LeandroAngelo E se não for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @LINQ Nossa eu juro que tinha lido `Action` no lugar de `Boolean`

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que percorrer um *array* recebido como parâmetro, usando [`params`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119086/101), e varrer todo ele em um laço, fazendo o `if` que deseja.

Se não se importar com performance dá para fazer com LINQ em uma linha.

[Dependendo do que deseja fazer alógica seria um pouco diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50455/101).

Se realmente é para receber vários campos de um objeto então seria melhor passar o objeto e fazer a varredura. Aí ou teria que fazer item por item ou usar [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101), o que tornaria o código bem mais lento, provavelmente só para economizar digitação, e não é simples selecionar campos, todos seriam usados, a não ser com uma lógica um pouco mais complicada, precisaria ver se compensa. Precisaria generalizar.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(Teste("João", "048", "abc"));
        WriteLine(Teste("João", "048", "abc", ""));
        WriteLine(Teste("", "João", "048", "abc"));
        WriteLine(Teste("", null));
        WriteLine(Teste2("", null));
        WriteLine(Teste2("", null, "João", "048", "abc"));
    }
    public static bool Teste(params string[] textos) {
        foreach (var item in textos) if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool Teste2(params string[] textos) => textos.Any(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gbT6Sa). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0n2pcx). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Comparing.cs).

Aproveitei e converti o código para o estilo C#.

Comment: Lambda expressions wins!